# image caption left aligned under centered image

Tags: html, image, caption

I have some images with captions.
The images are centered on the sites and the caption should be shown under the images. Very simple so far but here's the problem:
the captions should be left-aligned and start under the bottom-left-corner of the image (like in newspapers)

I can think of a solution with tables but I don't like it because tables are here to show table data and not images and image captions

table solution:

```
<table class="centered-table">
  <tr><td class="image"><img src="stackoverflow.jpg" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="caption">Unanswered question on stackoverflow.com</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` with a tiny bit of `display: table` to get the effect you want.

See this **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MadaraUchiha/wJMbX/)**

Answer (score 3):

Hmmmmmmm

```
<style>
    .centered {text-align:center;}
    .wrapper {display:inline-block; text-align:left;}
</style>
```

And

```
<div class="centered">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image"><img src="someimage.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="caption">Some caption text!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image"><img src="someimage.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="caption">Some caption text!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or what? :)

Comment: +1. But remove the div around the image, it's useless. I would also add this CSS: `.wrapper img { display: block; text-align: center; }` just in case the caption makes the `.wrapper` larger than the image.

Comment: Well in my opinion its a good idea to make a container for each element, so you can redesign/relayout the HTML without changing it. Here you can control each element. And yes you are right about the img css, smart thinking! :)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your picture and title in a div, and give it an inline-block display style.

```
<div id="article">
    <div class="title"><div>
        <img src="picture.jpg" />
        <em>Caption for the picture.</em>
    </div></div>
    <p>rest of the articlce...</p>
</div>
```

With CSS.

```
div.title
{
    text-align:center;
}
div.title > div
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
```